# Error during Nova compute package installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, openstack-nova

Error in command: python setup.py install

I am not getting the error. Please help

**This is the error**

```
>bash-4.2# python setup.py install
>ERROR:root:Error parsing
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/core.py", line 104, in pbr
attrs = util.cfg_to_args(path)
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/util.py", line 238, in cfg_to_args
>pbr.hooks.setup_hook(config)
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/hooks/__init__.py", line 27, in setup_hook
metadata_config.run()
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/hooks/base.py", line 29, in run
self.hook()
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/hooks/metadata.py", line 28, in hook
self.config['name'], self.config.get('version', None))
File "/sagar/nova/pbr-0.10.7-py2.7.egg/pbr/packaging.py", line 554, in get_version
raise Exception("Versioning for this project requires either an sdist"
Exception: Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed? error in setup command: 
Error parsing /sagar/nova/setup.cfg: 
Exception:      Versioning for this project requires either an sdist tarball, or access to an upstream git repository. Are you sure that git is installed?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't added git in PATH variable. I was facing similar issue myself while installing nova on Hyper V. Just updating the PATH variable did the trick